# Intersecting list of records

Tags: java, algorithm, list, data-structures

I have 2 lists -

- `List<String> RecordIdByPriority` and
- `List<String> RecordId`.

As the name suggests  - the first list contains records in the insertion order of priority.
The idea is to find the presence of the highest priority record from the second list.

If priority list contains `<A,D,E>`, and second contains `<B,E,M>` - expected output is 'E'.

Given that the second list is potentially large - what is the data structure/routine to achieve this in the most efficient way

Comment: You did not provide enough information to give a good suggestion. It depends on how these lists change over time. (I assume, you want to do this repeatedly)

Comment: The first 'reference' list is static - and would be used as look-up for a new 'second' list repeatedly

Comment: `Collections::retainAll` is a slight overkill IMO. Just loop in priority order in `RecordIdByPriority`, which inner-loops `RecordId`, check with `contains()` and return immediately on the first match.

Comment: Do you just want the single highest priority result or all intersecting elements in priority order? In the latter case, how large is the intersection typically?

Comment: The output expected is the single highest priority record found .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some one-time preprocessing, that turns the `List<String> RecordIdByPriority` into a `HashMap<String, Integer>` that maps each item on the list to its position in the list. In your example { A -> 0, D -> 1, E -> 2 }. Then make a single pass through the `RecordId` list to find the minimum element according to the hash map. Elements not found in the map have an implicit priority of +infinity.

This means you can find the element in O(n) where n is the length of the record id list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the classic loop should still be efficient for this.

```
public String getHighestPriorityRecord(List<String> recordIdByPriority, List<String> recordId) {
    for (String record : recordIdByPriority) {
        if (recordId.contains(record)) {
            return record;
        }
    }

    // Not found
    return null;
}
```

- Best: `O(1)`
- Average: `O(n log n)`?
- Worst: `O(n^2)`

If you want to speed it up, then you can make `recordId` into a `HashSet` (by creating a new instance of `HashSet`), so that `contains()` would be `O(1)`, which effectively turns this algorithm's worst case into `O(n)`.